# How can we click on an icon which is list in Python Selenium ('list' object has no attribute 'click' error)?

Tags: python, selenium, rpa

I am on an RPA project and I am trying an automation via a website. I am trying write xpad to click on the object I aim (with selenium) however it is a list and I get this error; ''list' object has no attribute 'click'' I paste the inspect part's image (ss) here and below my code.

```
site = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
site.get("websiteaddress")
site.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Findings and Action').click()
```

and also this one for the last row

```
fa = site.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='sasLeftNavNav']//li[.//span[text()='RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_icn']]/li[@id='RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5']")
fa.click()
```

Thank you in advance for the help !

inspect from the browser (partial):

```html
<li id="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5" role="menuitem" data-item="5" aria-label="Selected, Findings and Action" tabindex="0" class="sasLeftNavItemSelected" aria-selected="true"><span id="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_icn" data-sap-ui="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_icn" data-item="5" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Findings and Action" title="Findings and Action" data-sap-ui-icon-content="" class="sapUiIcon" style="font-family:'sas-icons'"></span><span class="sasLeftNavItemState" id="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_state" data-item="5"></span><span class="sasLeftNavItemLabel" title="Findings and Action" data-item="5">Findings and Action</span></li>

<span id="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_icn" data-sap-ui="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5_icn" data-item="5" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Findings and Action" title="Findings and Action" data-sap-ui-icon-content="" class="sapUiIcon" style="font-family:'sas-icons'"></span>

<::before></::before>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlkZO.png)

Answer (score 0):

*find_elements_by_partial_link_text()* function returns list of all found elements.
If you need just one element you can use *find_element_by_partial_link_text()* function.

However if you need to click to all of found elements matching your locator then you can use:

```
for element in site.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Findings and Action'):
    element.click()
```

Comment: When I write just element for the same code I got this: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Findings and Action"} When I write the code with for and in it gives no error but it does not click so it does not work

Comment: This means that there is no elements matching locators.
Can you try:

fa = site.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5']")

Comment: I have tried it already. When it gives the error I turned to partial_link_text. However, I tried it onces more after you said and that's the error again :( : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id='RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_appContainer_lfn_5']"}
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.82)

Comment: Seems like you are on wrong page then :)
Can you pls paste result of print(site.page_source)?

Comment: Hhaha really :D Pasting the result here like an answer then because it is too long

Answer (score 0):

```
<html class="sap-desktop  sapUiTheme-sas_corporate sapUiMedia-Std-Desktop sapUiMedia-StdExt-Desktop" dir="ltr" data-sap-ui-browser="cr99" data-sap-ui-os="win10" lang="en" data-sap-ui-animation="on"><head><base href="/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/signals.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/hasher.js"></script>
<style>
.gshHeader {
  border-color: #ec66eb;
  font-size: 11;
  margin-bottom: 4;
}
.gshDisplay {
  border-color: #6878b6;
  font-size: 10;
  margin-bottom: 19;
}
</style>


 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes/sas/hc/ui/commons/themes/sas_corporate/img/ico/SASLogo_toolbar.ico">
  <meta content="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes/sas/hc/ui/commons/themes/sas_corporate/img/ico/SASLogo_toolbar.ico" itemprop="image">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes/sas/hc/ui/commons/themes/sas_corporate/splash.css" media="screen">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">     
    
 <style type="text/css">.gshDisplay { border-color: #6878af; font-size: 14; margin-bottom: 11; }</style><script src="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js" data-sap-ui-module="sap/ui/core/library-preload.js"></script><script src="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/sas/hc/ui/core/library-preload.js" data-sap-ui-module="sas/hc/ui/core/library-preload.js"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes/sap/ui/core/themes/sas_corporate/library.css" id="sap-ui-theme-sap.ui.core" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes/sas/hc/ui/core/themes/sas_corporate/library.css" id="sap-ui-theme-sas.hc.ui.core" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><title>ING iModel (powered by SAS® Model Risk Management)</title></head>
  
 <body class="sapUiBody">
  
  
<style>
#sas-hc-splash-alertText {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px,0px,0px,0px);
}
</style>


  <script id="hc-config">
(function(){
  window['sap-ui-config'] = window['sap-ui-config'] || {};
  var config = window['sap-ui-config'];
  config.sas = config.sas || {};
  config.sas.contextPath='https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework'; 
  config.sas.appId='SASApplicationSwitcherBootstrap'; 
  config.language='tr-tr'; 
  config.rtl=false; 
  config.sas.crossDomainProxy='CASedCrossDomainProxy'; 
  config.sas.commonsRegistryUrl='https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/rest'; 
  config.sas.wipRegistryUrl='https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASWIPClientAccess/rest/services'; 
  config.sas.servicePlatform='WIP'; 
  config.sas.themeUrl='https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes'; 
  config.sas.webdocUrl='https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASWebDoc'; 
  config.sas.softwareComponentName='Risk Gov Frwk Mid-Tier'; 
  config.sas.applicationSwitcherEnabled=true; 
  config.sas.sessionTimeoutUrl='https%3A%2F%2Fimodel.ic.ing.net%3A8343%2FSASLogon%2FTimedOut.do%3F_locale%3Dtr_TR%26_sasapp%3DRisk%2BGov%2BFrwk%2BMid-Tier%26rgfContentId%3Dmrm'; 
  config.sas.sessionMaxInActiveInterval=1800; 
  config.sas.sessionTimeoutWarningDuration=300; 
  config.sas.userCapabilities=''; 
  config.sas.appName = 'ING iModel (powered by SAS\u00AE Model Risk Management)';
  config.theme = config.theme || 'sas_corporate';
  config.themeroots = config.themeroots || {};
  config.themeroots[config.theme] = config.themeroots[config.theme] || 'https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/themes';
}());
</script>
<script id="hc-precore" src="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/sas/hc/ui/core/preCore.js" data-loading="Yükleniyor" data-still-loading="Halen Yükleniyor"></script>  <script>
  (function(){
      var config = window['sap-ui-config'];
   config.modules = ['sas.hc.ui.core.library'];
   config.sas.bootTask = undefined;
   }());
  </script>
  <script src="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/resources/shcb1643626187000/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="hc-init">
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function(){
        sas.log.info("appSwitcher"+sas.applicationSwitcher);
        sas.applicationSwitcher.localizedStrings['discardUnsavedChanges.txt']='De\u011Fi\u015Fiklikleri atmak ve uygulamalardan \u00E7\u0131kmak m\u0131 istiyorsunuz?';
        sas.applicationSwitcher.localizedStrings['unsavedChangesNotification.txt']='A\u015Fa\u011F\u0131daki uygulamalarda kaydedilmemi\u015F de\u011Fi\u015Fiklikler bulunuyor:';
        
        $( window ).on('beforeunload',function(event){
            
            if(sas.applicationSwitcher.isDirtyMessageEnabled()===false)
                return;
        
            var unsavedChangesMessage=sas.applicationSwitcher.getUnsavedChangesMessage();
            if(unsavedChangesMessage===null){
                return;
            }
            else{
                event.returnValue=unsavedChangesMessage;
                return unsavedChangesMessage;
            }
        });
       
       sas.applicationSwitcher.gotoApp('RGF_HUB_Home_MRM', window.location.href, true, {'bootstrapping':true});
    });
  </script>
 

<div id="appsContainer" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><iframe id="RGF_HUB_Home_MRM_iframe" loaded="false" allowfullscreen="true" tabindex="0" src="https://imodel.ic.ing.net:8343/SASRiskGovernanceFramework/content/mrm?launchedFromAppSwitcher=true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-width: 0px;"></iframe></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).